# Ignoring template instantiation failures in C++20 concept specializations

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts, static-assert

Suppose I want to write a class `Collect` that provides me with the function to transfer the items of a given `std::vector<>` to a collection of any type.
Where transfering to a back-insertable collection is supported for all item types, but transfering to a associative collection (unordered_map, map) is only
supported if the items are variants of `std::pair<,>`.

To implement this, I started by defining concepts that identify the type of requested containers (Shortened & incomplete for clarity):

```cpp
/** Concept that checks whether the given type is a std::pair<> */
template<typename T> concept is_pair = requires(T pair) {
    typename T::first_type;
    typename T::second_type;
    {std::get<typename T::first_type>(pair)} -> std::convertible_to<typename T::first_type>;
    {std::get<typename T::second_type>(pair)} -> std::convertible_to<typename T::second_type>;
};

/** Concept that checks whether the given type is a back-insertable collection */
template<template<typename...> typename TContainer, typename TItem>
concept BackInsertableCollection = requires(TContainer<TItem> container, TItem item) {
    typename decltype(container)::value_type;
    container.push_back(item);
};

/** Concept that checks whether the given type is an associative collection */
template<template<typename...> typename TContainer, typename TItemKey, typename TItemValue>
concept AssocCollection = requires(TContainer<TItemKey, TItemValue> container, TItemKey key, TItemValue value) {
    typename decltype(container)::value_type;
    typename decltype(container)::key_type;
    typename decltype(container)::mapped_type;
    container[key] = value;
};
```

Then, I started implementing the `Collect` class I described above, by first defining its empty template form:

```cpp
/** Collector class that takes a std::vector<TItem> as argument,
 * and produces a new container of the requested type TContainer,
 * containing the items from the vector.
 */
template<template<typename...> typename TContainer, typename TItem>
struct Collect {};
```

I then create specializations of this class using the concepts defined above:

```cpp
/** Collect specialization for BackInsertable containers */
template<template<typename...> typename TContainer, typename TItem>
requires BackInsertableCollection<TContainer, TItem>
struct Collect<TContainer, TItem> {
    static auto collect(std::vector<TItem>& values) {
        TContainer<TItem> container;
        for(const auto& value : values) {
            container.push_back(value);
        }
        return container;
    }
};

/** Collect specialization for associative containers */
/** Requires items to be std::pair<>, automatically extracting key and value type for container */
template<template<typename...> typename TContainer, typename TItem>
requires is_pair<TItem> && AssocCollection<TContainer, typename TItem::first_type, typename TItem::second_type>
struct Collect<TContainer, TItem> {
    static auto collect(std::vector<TItem>& values) {
        TContainer<typename TItem::first_type, typename TItem::second_type> container;
        for(const auto& value : values) {
            container[value.first] = value.second;
        }
        return container;
    }
};
```

Collecting non-`std::pair<,>` items to back-insertable containers works fine. As does collecting `std::pair<>` items to associative containers.
However, collecting `std::pair<>` items into an `std::vector<>` leads to compiler errors:

```cpp
int main() {
    { // works: non-std::pair<> to back-insertible container
        using Item = std::string;
        std::vector<Item> input = {"1", "2"};
        auto output = Collect<std::vector, Item>::collect(input);
    }
    { // works: std::pair<> to associative container
        using Item = std::pair<int, std::string>;
        std::vector<Item> input = {{1, "1"}, {2, "2"}};
        auto output = Collect<std::unordered_map, Item>::collect(input);
    }
    { // compiler error: std::pair<> to back-insertible container
        using Item = std::pair<int, std::string>;
        std::vector<Item> input = {{1, "1"}, {2, "2"}};
        auto output = Collect<std::vector, Item>::collect(input);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The last case hits a `static_assert` failure within `std::vector`, because the `AssocCollection` concept takes key- and value-type from the `std::pair<,>`'s `first_type`, and `second_type`. If it does that and places these two types as first and second template parameter to `std::vector`, it provides an invalid argument to the `std::vector<>`'s allocator template-parameter.
Here is a link to the full example with the compiler errors: https://godbolt.org/z/oY3cfbrYE

I would have expected the concepts to behave more like SFINAE here, where such an error causes the template specialization to be ruled out, instead of leading to a compiler error. Is there a more C++20`ish way to get this to work, than falling back to SFINAE?

Comment: SFINAE will not suppress the error from `std::vector<int,std::string>::value_type` any more than this does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a more C++20`ish way to get this to work, than falling back
> to SFINAE?

The problem is that when `TContainer` models back-insertable collection, `Collect`'s partial specialization of associative collections will still instantiate constraints, which leads to invalid instantiations such as `std::vector<int,std::string>` to trigger `static_assert`.

You can add additional constraints to this partial specialization to block its instantiation when the former partial specialization has been satisfied.

```
/** Collect specialization for associative containers */
template<template<typename...> typename TContainer, typename TItem>
requires (!BackInsertableCollection<TContainer, TItem>) && 
         //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
         is_pair<TItem> && AssocCollection<TContainer, typename TItem::first_type, typename TItem::second_type>
struct Collect<TContainer, TItem> {
    static auto collect(std::vector<TItem>& values) {
        TContainer<typename TItem::first_type, typename TItem::second_type> container;
        for(const auto& value : values) {
            container[value.first] = value.second;
        }
        return container;
    }
};
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/6K5KEGY7M)